# Spring Boot Security redirect after successful login - undefined

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-boot

I have followed the [spring boot security tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) but the end result has an issue consisting in that *after successful login the browser is redirect to `/undefined`*.

I have even cloned the code referenced in the tutorial, thinking I have typed something wrong, or forgot to add a component or something. No, the same issue is there.

Searching on Stackoverflow I found out that you need to define the default success URL in the `configure` method of the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like so:

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/")
```

but still no go. Accessing a protected resource leads to the login page and upon successful login I don't get redirected to the protected resource. I get to the '/undefined' page. Forcing the success works, however:

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
```

... but this is not what I would need because after successful login the user should be redirected to secured resource (initially) requested.

---

Here's the relevant parts of the project:

**WebSecurityConfig:**

```
package ro.rinea.andrei.Security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package ro.rinea.andrei.Controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/salut")
    public String salut() {
        return "salut";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

There are views defined for `index`, `login` and `salut` (if needed I will add their contents)

and the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'tstBut'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mobile')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
}
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to your issue? If yes please accept the answer that helped you so other people (e.g. me) can find a solution.

Comment: Why isn't there an answer to the question? just work arounds!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add a successHandler to redirect like this:

```
private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
   ...
   .formLogin()
   .loginPage("/login")
   .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this is a workaround that I used.
First have a mapping for your root "/" that is unprotected

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView projectBase() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home");
}
```

Have it redirect to where you want the user to go initially like home for example

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getHome() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("account/home");
    model.addObject("user", userFacade.getJsonForUser(userFacade.getUserForClient()));
    return model;
}
```

Make sure the root url is open in your security configuration like...

```
 http.
    authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
```

What will happen is now it will hit the root /, and redirect to home which is restricted and send them to the loginpage with a return url of home. it will then write correctly as /home when they first login

For some reason spring security is not respecting the default success url, and it could be a configuration issue with your web server causing it. On my local machine I don't have this issue, but on some other machines I do. The workaround works in both places, since you always end up with a returnUrl.

Answer (score 0):

### 2024 method

Use **defaultSuccessUrl** to redirect users after successfull login. You could add a second argument (boolean alwaysUse), but I would not recommand it, it will always redirect users after success login.

```
.formLogin((form) -> form
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
    .permitAll())
.logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());
```